# MySql INSERT Failure

Tags: mysql, syntax

Why does the following query fails on MySql?

`NHibernate: INSERT INTO UserSetting (userId, key, value) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2);
?p0 = ccda78da-689d-4d86-ba72-d65eaf281edf [Type: Guid (0)], ?p1 = 'Hello' [Type: String (5)], ?p2 = 'World' [Type: String (5)]`

With this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, value) VALUES ('ccda78da-689d-4d86-ba72-d65eaf281edf', 'Hello', 'World')' at line 1"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO UserSetting (userId, `key`, value) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2)
```

Comment: @webwise: unfortunately, I'm not familiar with `NHibernate`. It is best to avoid the reserved keywords in the object names.

Answer (score 2):

Key is a reserved word, use ticks, example in link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html